# Adding records to memory optimized table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to add records to memory optimized table using EF like so:

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    db.Table.AddRange(newEntries);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

And get the error like below:

> SqlException: Accessing memory optimized tables using the READ
>   COMMITTED isolation level is supported only for autocommit
>   transactions. It is not supported for explicit or implicit
>   transactions. Provide a supported isolation level for the memory
>   optimized table using a table hint, such as WITH (SNAPSHOT).

How can I figure out the cause of this problem?

Comment: That error message tells you the cause, what about it do you not understand?

Comment: As adding a table hint to an EF query is quite uncomfortable, I recommend you use the `MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT` option on the database instead. [See also](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/transactions-with-memory-optimized-tables).

Comment: Can changing MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT cause problems with existing code/applications? It did work when I tried it on test, but in my case it's impossible to test all apps working on the production database.

Comment: @DavidG the cause was that EF does not add the WITH (SNAPSHOT) when using certain StoreGeneratedPattern option in EDMX, the error did not help me with that at all.

Comment: I cannot personally imagine a situation under which `MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT` makes for a breaking difference (other than not producing errors under certain circumstances). This is because the only scenario that changes behavior is single statements accessing one in-memory table under `READ COMMITTED`: without the option they will use `READ COMMITTED`, with the option they will use `SNAPSHOT`. The implementation may be subtly different, but if there's a scenario where you can actually come up with a difference I don't know how to engineer one -- not to say that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Because EF always uses an explicit transaction (or that's my understanding, at least) if all access is done through EF `MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT` is "completely safe" in that it only enables things to work that would have produced errors before (`READ COMMITTED/UNCOMMITTED` access without a table hint) while leaving alone the rest (higher isolation levels).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Following @Jeroen Mostert advice I did turn on `MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT` on the database and it worked without the need to fiddle with `StoreGeneratedPattern`. I still am a bit afraid to turn it on production database though.

**ORIGINAL:**

I've added logging:

```
 using (var db = new Context()) {
     db.Database.Log = l => Trace.WriteLine(l);
```

There was an INSERT with a SELECT from the same table (without the SNAPSHOT hint).

In .edmx, a timestamp field of the memory optimized table had `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `Identity`. The table has a SYSDEFAULT() CONSTRAINT.

Setting `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `None` caused `SaveChanges` to only produce INSERT and there was no exception.

In my case it was feasible to fetch the SYSDATETIME first, update the timestamp fields and then save them:

```
DateTime dbDate = await db.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>("SELECT SYSDATETIME()").SingleAsync(cancellationToken);
entries.ForEach(l => l.TimestampField = dbDate);
db.Table.AddRange(entries);
await db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I know this might not be optimal and does not help in every scenario.